# how to mark LVM raid1 PV as in-sync

Tags: lvm, raid1

I am recovering from bad sectors on both sides of my LVM raid setup.
(It's the backup server, dammit).  I have new disks and a new install.
I could wipe the backup partition and suck 1TB of data across a slow link, and maybe I'll be forced to do that.  One of the failed drives is mostly salvageable to read/pvmove stuff off, but the other drive has many read errors and auto-allocation failures, and is not coming back as far as LVM is concerned.

```
istari# lvs --all -o +devices | grep TapeDisks
  TapeDisks                  istari rwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     TapeDisks_rimage_0(0),TapeDisks_rimage_1(0)            
  [TapeDisks_rimage_0]       istari Iwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     /dev/sdb3(10731)                                       
  [TapeDisks_rimage_0]       istari Iwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     /dev/sdb3(100333)                                      
  [TapeDisks_rimage_0]       istari Iwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     /dev/sdb3(264174)                                      
  [TapeDisks_rimage_1]       istari vwi---r--- 800.00g                                                                                                            
  [TapeDisks_rmeta_0]        istari ewi---r---   4.00m                                                     /dev/sdb3(5963)                                        
  [TapeDisks_rmeta_1]        istari ewi---r---   4.00m
```

The capital I means that the "mirror or raid (I)mage out-of-sync", and perhaps this means that the file system is catastrophically broken.  Or maybe fsck can fix it and save some significant data transfer.  I can get it all from off-site, but this annoys me, so I'm asking.

I have tried:

```
istari# lvchange -ay --force /dev/istari/TapeDisks                 
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:32) failed: Invalid argument
```

and dmesg says:

```
[ 1303.485131] device-mapper: raid: Failed to read superblock of device at position 1
[ 1303.494755] md: pers->run() failed ...
[ 1303.494835] device-mapper: table: 253:32: raid: Failed to run raid array
[ 1303.494895] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

```
lvconvert --force --type linear /dev/istari/VirtualMachines
```

I read that I could grab the data off of /dev/sdb3 with the right offsets, as I also have the /etc/lvm from the broken disk in a safe place.